# Do Power Troopers revive each other?

Tags: borderlands-3

I'm in Atlas HQ, using Zane and the Digi-clone, I trigger the apparently guaranteed Power Troopers that are basically guarding the first Typhon Log.

And then I hide and basically send my clone to do all the work for me. Every once it a while, I get EXP, and notice a Trooper coming from their spawn point around the same time.

I'm not watching my foes because I don't want to get shot, but are the Troopers respawning, so I have to kill all 5 at around the same time?

I think Pink is their healer, maybe it's their power?

Answer (score 1):

No, the Power Troopers don't revive each other, it's just that you keep getting weird Clone EXP.

[What causes my digi-clone's death to give me EXP?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/386311/what-causes-my-digi-clones-death-to-give-me-exp)

---

Also, those Troopers are still around even after finishing that part of the Main Quest, triggered by walking near the Log. Good for grinding. Ish.

Comment: is there a reason you keep answering your own question as if you're not the OP? like, is your account some bot account that reposts questions/answers, or are you forgetting to switch off the burner?

Comment: @EarthToAccess - It's because I ask questions, no one answers and then I also find the answers.

Comment: i mean, that makes sense i suppose, but i'm still curious about the odd use of second-person like you're talking to someone else.

Comment: @EarthToAccess - Feels more right, for every answer to be in at least second person, talking to the viewer, instead of the answerer. If you wanna edit it, I won't stop you. I can't use the edit queue, too much rep so it auto-bypasses, so I don't know the community's thoughts on POV.

Comment: that's fine lmao that makes sense then. i saw my fair share of bots that showed up at some point reposting things across forums and pages across the internet, let alone StackExchange pages, so i was making sure that you weren't a hacked account or something lmfao