# What causes my digi-clone's death to give me EXP?

Tags: borderlands-3

Sometimes, when my Digi-Clone dies instead of just having the skill run out, I get a seemingly fixed amount of EXP from it. ~312 or so, as a Level ~30 Zane.

And seems to happen only / most often, while fighting Badass-type enemies?

But it doesn't happen every time? What causes it?

I've got the Double Barrel... Could the clone be killing itself due to me giving it Heavies, and I somehow get experience from that?